# reference lost in vs 2010 when adding a DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference

When I add a dll to my project in Visual Studio 2010 and then try to run my program, my reference is lost and I get the following error

Error   2   The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed just "Target framework" from ".Net Framework 4 client profile" to ".Net Framework 4"